# Using multiprocessing with Pyarrows' HdfsClient

Tags: python, multiprocessing, parquet, pyarrow

I have a toplevel function that gets a tuple containing a parquet filepath and column name.

The function loads just the column from the file, converts to pandas, than packs / serializes it to a standard form. Something like:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
from multiprocessing import Pool

def binarizer(file_data_tuple):
   ''' Read a Parquet column a file, binarize and return'''

   path, col_name, col_meta, native = file_data_tuple
   if not native: 
       # Either this or using a top level hdfs_con
       hdfs_con = pa.hdfs.connect(params)     
   read_pq = pq.read_table if native else hdfs_con.read_parquet

   arrow_col = read_pq(filepath, columns = (col_name,))
   bin_col = imported_binarizng_function(arrow_col)
   return bin_col

def read_binarize_parallel(filepaths):
    ''' Setup parallel reading and binarizing of a parquet file'''

    # list of tuples containing the filepath, column name, meta, and mode   
    pool_params = [(),..] 
    pool = Pool()
    for file in filepaths:
        bin_cols = pool.map(binarizer, pool_params)
        chunk =  b''.join(bin_cols)
        send_over_socket(chunk)
```

This works when I use native mode, aka reading files from the local filesystem.

However, if I try to read over hdfs, I get weird (to me) Arrow errors, both when I open a connection inside each process and when I try to use the same one. Here's a compacted version of the error:

> [libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse
>   message of type "Hdfs.Internal.RpcResponseHeaderProto" because it is
>   missing required fields: callId, status [libprotobuf ERROR
>   google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type
>   "Hdfs.Internal.RpcResponseHeaderProto" because it is missing required
>   fields: callId, status [libprotobuf ERROR
>   google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type
>   "Hdfs.Internal.RpcResponseHeaderProto" because it is missing required
>   fields: callId, status [libprotobuf ERROR
>   google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type
>   "Hdfs.Internal.RpcResponseHeaderProto" because it is missing required
>   fields: callId, status 2018-01-09 21:41:47.939006, p10007,
>   th139965275871040, ERROR Failed to invoke RPC call "getFileInfo" on
>   server "192.168.0.101:9000": RpcChannel.cpp: 703: HdfsRpcException:
>   RPC channel to "192.168.0.101:9000" got protocol mismatch: RPC channel
>   cannot find pending call: id = 3.
>       @   Unknown
>
> ```
> @   Unknown
> @   arrow::io::HadoopFileSystem::GetPathInfo(std::string const&, arrow::io::HdfsPathInfo*)
> @   __pyx_f_7pyarrow_3lib_16HadoopFileSystem__path_info(__pyx_obj_7pyarrow_3lib_HadoopFileSystem*,
> ```
>
> _object*, arrow::io::HdfsPathInfo*)
>       @   __pyx_pw_7pyarrow_3lib_16HadoopFileSystem_15isfile(_object*, _object*)
>       @   Unknown
>       @   Unknown
>
> ```
> @   Unknown
> ```
>
> 2018-01-09 21:41:47.939103, p10007, th139965275871040, INFO Retry
>   idempotent RPC call "getFileInfo" on server "192.168.0.101:9000"
>   2018-01-09 21:41:47.939357, p10010, th139965275871040, ERROR Failed to
>   invoke RPC call "getFileInfo" on server "192.168.0.101:9000":
>   RpcChannel.cpp: 780: HdfsRpcException: RPC channel to
>   "192.168.0.101:9000" got protocol mismatch: RPC channel cannot parse
>   response header.
>       @   Unknown
>
> ```
> @   Unknown
> @   arrow::io::HadoopFileSystem::GetPathInfo(std::string const&, arrow::io::HdfsPathInfo*)
> @   __pyx_f_7pyarrow_3lib_16HadoopFileSystem__path_info(__pyx_obj_7pyarrow_3lib_HadoopFileSystem*,
> ```
>
> _object*, arrow::io::HdfsPathInfo*)
>       @   __pyx_pw_7pyarrow_3lib_16HadoopFileSystem_13isdir(_object*, _object*)
>       @   Unknown
>       @   Unknown
>
> ```
> @   Unknown
> @2018-01-09 21:41:47.939406, p10008, th139965275871040, ERROR Failed to invoke RPC call "getFileInfo" on server
> ```
>
> "192.168.0.101:9000": RpcChannel.cpp: 780: HdfsRpcException: RPC
>   channel to "192.168.0.101:9000" got protocol mismatch: RPC channel
>   cannot parse response header.
>       @   Unknown
>
> ```
> @   Unknown
> @   arrow::io::HadoopFileSystem::GetPathInfo(std::string const&, arrow::io::HdfsPathInfo*)
> @   __pyx_f_7pyarrow_3lib_16HadoopFileSystem__path_info(__pyx_obj_7pyarrow_3lib_HadoopFileSystem*,
> ```
>
> _object*, arrow::io::HdfsPathInfo*)
>       @   __pyx_pw_7pyarrow_3lib_16HadoopFileSystem_13isdir(_object*, _object*)
>       @   Unknown
>
> ```
> @   Unknown 2018-01-09 21:41:47.939422, p10013, th139965275871040, ERROR Failed to invoke RPC call "getFileInfo" on server
> ```
>
> "192.168.0.101:9000": RpcChannel.cpp: 780: HdfsRpcException: RPC
>   channel to "192.168.0.101:9000" got protocol mismatch: RPC channel
>   cannot parse response header.
>       @   Unknown
>
> ```
> @   Unknown
> @   arrow::io::HadoopFileSystem::GetPathInfo(std::string const&, arrow::io::HdfsPathInfo*)
> @   __pyx_f_7pyarrow_3lib_16HadoopFileSystem__path_info(__pyx_obj_7pyarrow_3lib_HadoopFileSystem*,
> ```
>
> _object*, arrow::io::HdfsPathInfo*)
>       @   __pyx_pw_7pyarrow_3lib_16HadoopFileSystem_13isdir(_object*, _object*)
>       @   Unknown
>
> ```
> @   Unknown
> @2018-01-09 21:41:47.939431, p10009, th139965275871040, ERROR Failed to invoke RPC call "getFileInfo" on server
> ```
>
> "192.168.0.101:9000": RpcChannel.cpp: 780: HdfsRpcException: RPC
>   channel to "192.168.0.101:9000" got protocol mismatch: RPC channel
>   cannot parse response header.
>       @   Unknown
>
> ```
> @   Unknown
> @   arrow::io::HadoopFileSystem::GetPathInfo(std::string const&, arrow::io::HdfsPathInfo*)
> @   __pyx_f_7pyarrow_3lib_16HadoopFileSystem__path_info(__pyx_obj_7pyarrow_3lib_HadoopFileSystem*,
> ```
>
> _object*, arrow::io::HdfsPathInfo*)
>       @   __pyx_pw_7pyarrow_3lib_16HadoopFileSystem_13isdir(_object*, _object*)
>       @   Unknown
>
> ```
> @   Unknown
> @   @   Unknown
> Unknown 2018-01-09 21:41:47.939457, p10012, th139965275871040, ERROR Failed to invoke RPC call "getFileInfo" on server
> ```
>
> "192.168.0.101:9000": RpcChannel.cpp: 780: HdfsRpcException: RPC
>   channel to "192.168.0.101:9000" got protocol mismatch: RPC channel
>   cannot parse response header.
>       @   Unknown
>
> ```
> @   Unknown
> @   arrow::io::HadoopFileSystem::GetPathInfo(std::string const&, arrow::io::HdfsPathInfo*)
> @   __pyx_f_7pyarrow_3lib_16HadoopFileSystem__path_info(__pyx_obj_7pyarrow_3lib_HadoopFileSystem*,
> ```
>
> _object*, arrow::io::HdfsPathInfo*)
>       @   __pyx_pw_7pyarrow_3lib_16HadoopFileSystem_13isdir(_object*, _object*)
>       @   Unknown
>       @   Unknown
>
> ```
> @   Unknown
> @   Unknown
> Unknown
> @   Unknown binarizing process filepath: /parquet_430mb/5e6.parquet
> @   Unknown
> Unknown
> @   Unknown
>
> @   Unknown
>
>
> @   Unknown
> ```
>
> 2018-01-09 21:41:47.939854, p10010, th139965275871040, INFO Retry
>   idempotent RPC call "getFileInfo" on server "192.168.0.101:9000"
>
> 2018-01-09 21:41:47.939864, p10013, th139965275871040, INFO Retry
>   idempotent RPC call "getFileInfo" on server "192.168.0.101:9000"
>   2018-01-09 21:41:47.939866, p10008, th139965275871040, INFO Retry
>   idempotent RPC call "getFileInfo" on server "192.168.0.101:9000"
>   2018-01-09 21:41:47.939868, p10012, th139965275871040, INFO Retry
>   idempotent RPC call "getFileInfo" on server "192.168.0.101:9000"
>   2018-01-09 21:41:47.939868, p10009, th139965275871040, INFO Retry
>   idempotent RPC call "getFileInfo" on server "192.168.0.101:9000"
>   2018-01-09 21:41:47.940813, p10014, th139965275871040, ERROR Failed to
>   invoke RPC call "getFileInfo" on server "192.168.0.101:9000":
>   RpcChannel.cpp: 780: HdfsRpcException: RPC channel to
>   "192.168.0.101:9000" got protocol mismatch: RPC channel cannot parse
>   response header.
>       @   Unknown
>
> ```
> @   Unknown
> @   arrow::io::HadoopFileSystem::GetPathInfo(std::string const&, arrow::io::HdfsPathInfo*)
> @   __pyx_f_7pyarrow_3lib_16HadoopFileSystem__path_info(__pyx_obj_7pyarrow_3lib_HadoopFileSystem*,
> ```
>
> _object*, arrow::io::HdfsPathInfo*)
>       @   __pyx_pw_7pyarrow_3lib_16HadoopFileSystem_13isdir(_object*, _object*)
>       @   Unknown
>
> ```
> @   Unknown
> ```
>
> 2018-01-09 21:41:47.940937, p10014, th139965275871040, INFO Retry
>   idempotent RPC call "getFileInfo" on server "192.168.0.101:9000"
>   2018-01-09 21:41:47.944352, p10011, th139965275871040, ERROR Failed to
>   invoke RPC call "getFileInfo" on server "192.168.0.101:9000":
>   RpcChannel.cpp: 393: HdfsRpcException: Failed to invoke RPC call
>   "getFileInfo" on server "192.168.0.101:9000"
>       @   Unknown
>       @   Unknown
>
> ```
> @   Unknown
> @   arrow::io::HadoopFileSystem::GetPathInfo(std::string const&, arrow::io::HdfsPathInfo*)
> @   __pyx_f_7pyarrow_3lib_16HadoopFileSystem__path_info(__pyx_obj_7pyarrow_3lib_HadoopFileSystem*,
> ```
>
> _object*, arrow::io::HdfsPathInfo*)
>       @   __pyx_pw_7pyarrow_3lib_16HadoopFileSystem_13isdir(_object*, _object*)
>       @   Unknown
>
> ```
> @   Unknown Caused by TcpSocket.cpp: 127: HdfsNetworkException: Write 124 bytes failed to "192.168.0.101:9000": (errno: 32) Broken
> ```
>
> pipe
>       @   Unknown
>       @   Unknown
>
> ```
> @   Unknown
> @   arrow::io::HadoopFileSystem::GetPathInfo(std::string const&, arrow::io::HdfsPathInfo*)
> @   __pyx_f_7pyarrow_3lib_16HadoopFileSystem__path_info(__pyx_obj_7pyarrow_3lib_HadoopFileSystem*,
> ```
>
> _object*, arrow::io::HdfsPathInfo*)
>       @   __pyx_pw_7pyarrow_3lib_16HadoopFileSystem_13isdir(_object*, _object*)
>       @   Unknown
>       @   Unknown
>
> ```
> @   Unknown
> ```
>
> 2018-01-09 21:41:47.944519, p10011, th139965275871040, INFO Retry
>   idempotent RPC call "getFileInfo" on server "192.168.0.101:9000"
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ArrowIOError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>
> /home/parquet_sender.pyc in insert_files_parallel(self)
>       374             # print ('372 sqparquet filepath:', filepath)
>       375             params_with_path_and_mode = [col_params+(filepath, native) for col_params in pool_params]
>   --> 376             bin_col = self.pool.map(read_binarize, params_with_path_and_mode)
>       377             got ('map complete')
>       378             num_rows = bin_col[0][2]
>
> /usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.pyc in map(self, func,
>   iterable, chunksize)
>       249         '''
>       250         assert self._state == RUN
>   --> 251         return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
>       252
>       253     def imap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=1):
>
> /usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.pyc in get(self, timeout)
>       556             return self._value
>       557         else:
>   --> 558             raise self._value
>       559
>       560     def _set(self, i, obj):
>
> ArrowIOError: HDFS: GetPathInfo failed

I'd be glad to have any feedback on the cause of this error, and how I should go about using parallel parquet loading.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a bug related to multiprocessing serialization details. I have opened a bug report here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1986